# OpenShift AWS Storage Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift-origin

We are having multiple issues with the OpenShift AWS storage plugin. We have everything configured and we can utilize AWS EBS volumes, the issue is with the automation.

According to the documentation, if you add the annotation "volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class": "foo" to your PVC, it will automatically create the EBS volume. It does create the volume, but it seems random as to which zone it will create it in. We have the zones set correctly in the /etc/aws/aws.conf.

Another issue we are experiencing is if for any reason the POD moves to another instance, the volume does not follow automatically. We end up having to manually detach the volume from the instance the POD was previously running on, and manually attach it to the correct one. This is not the case for when we first create volume and pv object. It will attach itself to the correct instance the first time we deploy the POD.

Is my understanding / expectations incorrect? Or am I doing something wrong? If any additional information is needed please let me know.